# Why would an ancient temple be dedicated to both Poseidon and Artemis?

Tags: greek, olympians, poseidon, artemis

Why is [this](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/artifact?name=Eleusis,%20Temple%20of%20Artemis%20and%20Poseidon&object=building) temple dedicated to both deities? I can't find a connection between them in either myth or theme.

Comment: Some nervous Greeks were covering all their bases?

Comment: I don't have any sources, but straight off the bat I can tell you that it has to do with the tides. That is basically the only connection between the moon and water.

Comment: But there are no perceptible tides in the eastern Mediterranean.

Comment: A different hypothesis:  a poorer Greek polis might dedicate a temple to both its patron deity and to a second god (unrelated in 'myth and theme').  Smaller communities obviously didn't have the resources to build separate temples for all the pantheon.

Answer (score 3):

Well, it was a temple that just had two separate reasons to be built.

[Book.](https://books.google.com/books?id=lSyY-OWFuGIC&pg=PA160&lpg=PA160&dq=Artemis%20Propylaia%20and%20Poseidon%20Pater&source=bl&ots=fzmzJMFtLT&sig=j6TcpjL_ceXmJ6ShRQjIoSM0ZX0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjqxuDJz6XLAhUMRiYKHdLaBOMQ6AEIPjAH#v=onepage&q=Artemis%20Propylaia%20and%20Poseidon%20Pater&f=false)

[image]

Since Poseidon was involved in Athens-Elusis relationship, and Artemis was the Propylaea(1) of Eleusis, so they made one temple to honor both of them.

(1) prop·y·lae·um- the entrance to the Acropolis at Athens.